# How to drop and recreate a table with SQLAlchemy without unnecessary reflects?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, metadata

I'm considering restructuring database management (mostly Postgres) with the use of SQLAlchemy Core, but I found that if I use built in functions such as insert or create, instead of passing textual SQL, it gets really slow.
It's a common use case in my programs to get a table by name (check if it exists), drop it if it exists and then recreate it. I found both recreating the table with a new Metadata object and reflecting the existing Metadata object rather slow, is there a way to work around this? How could I reduce the number of times the database is accessed?

For example:

```
def create_table(self, schema_name, table_name, data, primary_key=None, creation_mode=CREATION_MODE_DROP,
                 auto_transaction_mode=True):

    meta = MetaData(self.engine)
    meta.reflect(bind=self.engine, schema=schema_name)

    if isinstance(data, (list, set, KeysView)):
        column_definition = [Column(i, String) for i in data]
    else:
        column_definition = [Column(i, j) for i, j in data]

    if primary_key:
        column_definition.append(PrimaryKeyConstraint(primary_key))

    if creation_mode == CREATION_MODE_DROP:
        try:
            table = meta.tables[f'{schema_name}.{table_name}']
            table.drop(self.engine)
        except KeyError:
            pass
        table = Table(table_name, meta, *column_definition, extend_existing=True, schema=schema_name)
        table.create(self.engine)

    elif creation_mode == CREATION_MODE_IF_NOT_EXISTS:
        table = Table(table_name, MetaData(), *column_definition, schema=schema_name)
        table.create(self.engine, checkfirst=True)
```

Comment: The best "workaround" would be design the system properly. The concept "common use case in my programs to get a table by name (check if it exists), drop it if it exists and then recreate it" is a very poor design. Just create the table once, externally to your process, If you need it cleared of data for each run then delete all rows or truncate it before the process runs. Let me assure if the table does not exist the first time it is used, Postgres will let you know.

Comment: @Belayer, Every day I pull data I don't know if the columns are still the same or they've changed so the tables need to be dropped.
"Let me assure if the table does not exist the first time it is used, Postgres will let you know" - my point is exactly that I don't want to get an error.